# Get the instance of google map which is already on DOM

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom, google-maps-api-3, sapui5

I have a Google map which is already on the DOM with some markers on it. I created it and bound it to the DOM with an XML view in SAP UI 5.

```
<gmaps:Map id="map1" class="googleMap" height="600px" width="100%" zoom="4" lat ="100" lng = "80"></gmaps:Map>
```

Now I need to add a few markers in JS to the already existing view. But I am unable to get the existing map object.

I am getting this error `setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama` when I tried to get the instance like this:

```
document.getElementById('mapContainer')
```

Is there any workaround for this? As I created the map in XML I don't have the map object in Javascript.

Comment: get a refrence to the control try this.byId("map1") in your controller, else sap.ui.getCore().byId("map1"), SAPUI5 abstracts the DOM

Comment: Hi.. It worked if i give this.byId("map1").map   Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If the map div has and id named `id="map1"`, to obtain the element you need

```
 document.getElementById('map1')
```

Remember that once you have stored your map object in a window level vars you can refer to the map using this object.

```
<script>
    var map 
     .....
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), mapOptions); 
</script>
```